# Sending a row of 2d array as arguement

Tags: c++, c, function, arguments, kernighan-and-ritchie

1234ould
1234567ould
12ould

What I want to do is take a row of above 2D array pass it as a argument to a "strindex()" which returns the index where the "ould" happens to be in the line and if not it returns -1 . Then this index value is assinged to a element of the array "q[]" . When all the lines are completed then then the index of the rightmost occurance of "ould" from all the lines is printed.

```
int strindex(char s[],char t[])
{   int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';++i)
    {   for(j=i,k=0;t[k]!='\0'&&t[k]==s[j];k++,j++)
            ;
        if(k>0 && t[k]=='\0')
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int getline(char s[],int lim)
{   int i,c;
    i=0;
    while((--lim)>0 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n')
        s[i++]=c;
    if(c=='\n')
        s[i++]='\n';
    s[i]='\0';
    return i;
}

void main(void)
{   char line[MAXLIM],p[10][MAXLIM];
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,q[10],max;
    while((getline(line,MAXLIM))>0)
    {   for(;j<strlen(line);j++)
        {   p[i][j] = line[j];
        }
i++;
}
***max=0;
for(;k<i;++k)
{       
    q[k]=strindex(p[k],pattern);

    if(q[k]>max)
    {   
        max=q[k];
    }***
}


getch();
clrscr();

}
```

But as I debugged the program, it ran correctly for first line assigning max=4 but after it as i saw the value of q[k] it was assigned -1 for both lines and hence ruining my program .
IMPORTANT : The strindex() first parameter takes a 1D array so instead of p[k][] I wrote p[k] .
IMPORTANT : *** is the main part of program.

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Minimal Complete Verifiable Example added . Thanks @Eric Postpischil

Comment: This is not a complete or verifiable example. `pattern` is not defined. `MAXLIM` is not defined. `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` are not included. The two instances of `***` interfere with compilation. The code should be compilable: When somebody copies your code, pastes it into a file, and compiles it, it should compile with no changes needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When copying `line` into `p[i]` in the first loop in `main`, `j` is not set to zero. It is set to zero once before the first loop begins, but then the first copy increments `j`, and it remains at this incremented value, so it is not zero when the next attempt to copy a line starts.

Additionally, the code fails to ensure that each line copied into `p[i]` is terminated with a null character.

Comment: Thanks @Eric Postpischil and sorry for the inconvenience caused due to bad code 